# c# Adding strings in List<Tuple<>> with XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, list, tuples, xmltextreader

Ok, i have a `List` in which i want to add some data from an Xlm file. My `List` looks like that :

```
List<Tuple<string,string,string>> BookList;
```

And my Xml file looks like this :

```
<Book>
  <Name>BookName</Name>
  <Genre>BookGenre</Genre>
  <Year>BookYear</Year>
</Book>
```

What i want is to read from the xml file, and every time i read a `XmlNodeType.Text` add it inside the list. But how can i add lets say when i find the first `XmlNodeType.Text` in the fisrt string, then when i read the second `XmlNodeType.Text` in the second string of the list ....
What im doing now is this :

```
int count = 0;
string name,genre,year;
 while (reader.Read())
 {
    if (count.Equals(3))
    {
       BookList.Add(Tuple.Create(name,genre,year));
       count = 0;
    }//if

    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
       case XmlNodeType.Text:
       switch (count)
       {
          case 0:
             name = reader.Value;
             count++;
             break;
          case 1:
             genre = reader.Value;
             count++;
             break;
          case 2:
             year = reader.Value;
             count++;
             break;

        }//switch
        break;
    }//switch
 }//while
```

Is there anyway to avoid using this ugly `switch(count)` ?

Comment: Have you considered creating a `Book` class with those properties and using the `XmlSerializer` instead?

Comment: Nope... but now you gave a starting point. Going to check it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a foreach loop for your nodes instead of the switch count